# Way to extract generic type into variable

Tags: kotlin

So I want to do this:

```
class Person<T: BaseType> {
     val clazz = T::class // That's what I'm trying to achieve
}
```

Of course, I'm getting an error "Cannot use 'T' as a reified type parameter. Use a class instead."

Comment: This isn't possible due to Type Erasure: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that but there is a workaround I usually use:

```kotlin
class Person<T : Any>(val clazz: KClass<T>)

inline fun <reified T : Any> Person(): Person<T> {
    return Person(T::class)
}
```

Usage:

```kotlin
Person<String>()
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to add a little bit to adam's answer. obviously, it's better to pass the class into the constructor. now you can create a static `invoke` function to make it look nicer.

```
class Person<T: Any>(val clazz: KClass<T>) {

    companion object {
        inline operator fun <reified T: Any> invoke() = Person(T::class)
    }
}
```

then you can use it like there is no type erasure

```
val person = Person<String>()
```